# Memory management with blocks when class object is released

Tags: ios, block, memory-management

Assuming an example block as shown below executed.

```
[testBlock testPerformWithBlock:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (finished) {
       self.textField.text = @"Finished";
       NSLog(@"Edited to add an textfield update inside block");

    }
}];
```

What will happen if I pop the view controller that contains the object testBlock before the block returns the value of BOOL. Will the objects get deallocated properly?

Comment: Block statement retains the object on which it is calling, and it will release it when block statement executes.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra: that is irrelevant in this case. the block is not capturing any variables at all

Answer (score 0):

Everything inside a block is retained until the block is released from memory. If the object `testBlock` is still executing `testPerformWithBlock` and the block is still alive, then everything inside the block is retained.

You are only doing an `NSLog` in there, so nothing will change.

However, if you do this:

```
if (finished) {
    [self doSomething];
}
```

`self` is being used, and it will be retained, so take some caution if you are storing the blocks in some ivar somewhere

Comment: Is it possible to release the block when view controller is popped?

Comment: I dont know about who downvoted, but would like to know what should be   done to if there block contains `[self doSomething];` as in your example while popping the view controller

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are asking. There is no problem with memory management in your example. If you did not explicitly retain something, you do not need to explicitly release it.

Comment: Assuming the block consists of an object say textfield of ViewController, what happens then? Will the view controller be deallocated properly?

Comment: what do you mean "the block consists of an object"? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: I mean instead of NSLog as used in my example, if I use `textfield.text = @"Test";` where textField is an ibOutlet in the current viewcontroller.

Comment: @Rajkumar: if `textField` is an instance variable, you are implicitly using `self`, which means the block will retain `self`. If `testBlock` is also an instance variable, then you likely have a retain cycle. You should look at other questions about what to do about retain cycles.

Answer (score 0):

You will get warning that strongly capturing self inside block will lead to retain cycle it will not crash but its not proper you need to do as they say strong weak dance.You can do this.

```
__weak typeof(self)ref=self;

^(<your bock>){

__strong typeof(ref)strongSelf=ref;

if(strongSelf)//or if(!strongSelf)return;
{
[strongSelf-><variable>  methodCall];

}
};
```

Answer (score -2):

There will be no deallocated error.
Though the retainCount of "testBlock" will not change after the invocation, the block will not be released before it runs to the end.
The result is that program will run perfectly no matters "testBlock" dealloc or not.

The sample codes following:

```
- (void)lazyFetchingImage:(void (^)(void))finishBlock {
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:finishBlock];
}
MainVCAppDelegate *dd = [MainVCAppDelegate new];
NSLog(@"count==%i",[dd retainCount]);
[dd lazyFetchingImage:^{
    NSLog(@"22");
}];
NSLog(@"count==%i",[dd retainCount]);
[dd release];
```

The out put should be :
count==1
count==1
22